# Java how to compare string, String compare problem

Tags: java, string

I have problem with string comparison in Java. I have 2 nearly similar strings, but they are not equal, because one contains - (44) char and another contains - (8211) char. Can someone help me with case, that this strings are equals. I tried this in code, but it doesn't work:

```
cellValue.replaceAll("\u0045", "\u8211");
byte[] bytes = cellValue.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset());
String cellValueUtf8 = new String(bytes, Charset.defaultCharset());
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I wrote this method, and it works as I expect:

```
public static String normalizeDashChar(String toNormalize) {
    char[] bytes = toNormalize.toCharArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        if(bytes[i] == (char)45) {
            bytes[i] = (char)8211;
        }
    }

    return new String(bytes);
}
```

Comment: You do not need to reinvent the wheel. `String#replace` will do your job. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64486404/10819573) for the explanation. Note that I've not downvoted your answer .

Answer (score 0):

`String`s are constant; their values cannot be changed after they are created. Thus, [`String#replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) returns a new `String` i.e. this operation doesn't change `cellValue`. Also, note that `String#replaceAll` takes a regex as the first parameter.

You need [`String#replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)), which replaces **all occurrences** of `oldChar` in the given string with `newChar`, instead of `String#replaceAll`.

Replace

```
cellValue.replaceAll("\u0045", "\u8211");
```

with

```
cellValue = cellValue.replace('\u0045', '\u8211');
```

in order for the changed value to be assigned to `cellValue`.

Comment: I tryed to give there cellValue = cellValue.replaceAll("\u0045", "\u8211");, but it is without effect.

Comment: @PetrKostroun - please check the updated answer.